# Copy Parameter Context NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi UI and NiFi Registry, I created group of processors with parameter context and started version control. Now I want to clone this processors group with different parameter context. I found next:

> Import Flow

> The following story depicts the steps required to import the flow that was developed above into a new environment and make use of it.
> Drag Process Group onto Canvas
> Choose 'Import...' and select "Replicate DB to Kafka" flow
> User will be prompted to select a local Parameter Context to use for the Process Group:
>
> - Select an existing local context
> - Create new context, with values initially populated from the values saved in Flow Registry
> - **Create new context, by copying values from an existing local context**

I done this step, but I don't see this options, what i'm doing wrong? How can I create various parameter contexts based on existed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the options, download NiFi CLI and execute 2 commands:

```
nifi export-param-context -o your_path_to_save -pcid your_pc_id -u your_nifi_url  
nifi import-param-context -u your_nifi_url -i your_path_from_load -pcn name_pc
```

Comment: Is there any other option that doesn't involve access to the server containing the nifi installation? I only have access to the NiFi canvas  and registery, is it possible to import the parameter contexts and than export them through those?